# Thorough SharePoint 2010 development book suggestion?

Tags: books, development

I'm looking for a developer's book that would be quite in-depth and works from the basics to advanced stuff without requiring previous knowledge of MOSS 2007.

I would like the book to explain basics of the SharePoint development framework and class library and then go off with all kinds of common development practices in SharePoint . Including advanced stuff like integrating WCF services (including RIA services for Silverlight support) etc.

Comment: You should mark this kind of questions (with multiple answers) as Community Wiki

Comment: Converted to wiki as per Anders suggestion above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert - Most SharePoint development books tend to cover a broad amount of information at a relatively shallow depth.  They may cover the object model, but also focus on developing for SharePoint's features such as collaboration, search, etc.  There are plenty of books that I like, such as: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-SharePoint-2010-Development.productCd-0470529423,descCd-tableOfContents.html, but I don't know that it will cover everything that you want.

There are some online (downloadable) resources that may be more thorough:

SharePoint 2010 SDK [[Online]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253.aspx) [[Download]](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f0c9daf3-4c54-45ed-9bde-7b4d83a8f26f&displaylang=en)

Patterns and Practices [[Online]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx) [[Download]](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=64b55569-2168-4545-8b7c-f185b2cf967d&displaylang=en)

Developer Training Kit (with Hands On Labs) [[Download]](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=83A80A0F-0906-4D7D-98E1-3DD6F58FF059&displaylang=en)

Also, for the first time I think ever, Microsoft has made the TechEd videos/slide decks available online for free.  There were a slew of sessions related to SharePoint 2010 this year: http://www.msteched.com/Tracks/OfficeAndSharePoint

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I have grown quite fond of the book by Sahil Malik ["Building Solutions for SharePoint 2010"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430228652). Specifically for building SharePoint web parts you should look at Wictor Wiléns ["SharePoint 2010 Web pars in action"](http://www.facebook.com/pages/SharePoint-2010-Web-Parts-in-Action/388139167480)

Answer (score 4):

I've read a couple of books this summer on SharePoint 2010 including some of the mentioned here. The one I find most valuable is the free PDF book released by the SharePoint Patterns & Practices team called *Developing applications for Microsoft SharePoint 2010*. It can be downloaded from http://spg.codeplex.com/releases/view/48412.

This book is not for absolute newbies, it expects you to have some knowledge about SharePoint programming, but it is an excellent resource of how to do what in a correct way in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It will be beneficial for the SharePoint Developer to learn and effectively use PowerShell. A few of the books suggested are -

- [Automating SharePoint 2010 with Windows PowerShell 2.0](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470939206.html)
- [PowerShell for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Administrators](http://www.mhprofessional.com/product.php?isbn=0071747974)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite surprised that [Inside SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742318.aspx) by Andrew Connell et al hasn't been mentioned. It's provides a great overview of the architecture along with a selection of decent examples and I often refer to it.